# Using Qt -static, what lib is required for QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher & QWindowsUiaWrapper?

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking

Trying to make a program cross-platform, QT is required to be linked statically. I am struggling with dependencies.

After several hours researching, I managed to get the dependencies missing down to the following errors, for which I could not find much information around.

As an additional information, I could not include Qt5PlatformSupport, which does not seems to exists in Qt 5.12.2

```
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiaaccessibility.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class QWindowsUiaWrapper * __cdecl QWindowsUiaWrapper::instance(void)" (?instance@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl QWindowsUiaAccessibility::handleWmGetObject(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,long,long *)" (?handleWmGetObject@QWindowsUiaAccessibility@@SA_NPAUHWND__@@IJPAJ@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiaaccessibility.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::ready(void)" (?ready@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QWindowsUiaAccessibility::notifyAccessibilityUpdate(class QAccessibleEvent *)" (?notifyAccessibilityUpdate@QWindowsUiaAccessibility@@UAEXPAVQAccessibleEvent@@@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiaaccessibility.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::clientsAreListening(void)" (?clientsAreListening@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QWindowsUiaAccessibility::notifyAccessibilityUpdate(class QAccessibleEvent *)" (?notifyAccessibilityUpdate@QWindowsUiaAccessibility@@UAEXPAVQAccessibleEvent@@@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiaaccessibility.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::returnRawElementProvider(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,long,struct IRawElementProviderSimple *)" (?returnRawElementProvider@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEJPAUHWND__@@IJPAUIRawElementProviderSimple@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl QWindowsUiaAccessibility::handleWmGetObject(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,long,long *)" (?handleWmGetObject@QWindowsUiaAccessibility@@SA_NPAUHWND__@@IJPAJ@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiamainprovider.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::hostProviderFromHwnd(struct HWND__ *,struct IRawElementProviderSimple * *)" (?hostProviderFromHwnd@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEJPAUHWND__@@PAPAUIRawElementProviderSimple@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual long __stdcall QWindowsUiaMainProvider::get_HostRawElementProvider(struct IRawElementProviderSimple * *)" (?get_HostRawElementProvider@QWindowsUiaMainProvider@@UAGJPAPAUIRawElementProviderSimple@@@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiamainprovider.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::raiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent(struct IRawElementProviderSimple *,int,struct tagVARIANT,struct tagVARIANT)" (?raiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEJPAUIRawElementProviderSimple@@HUtagVARIANT@@1@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl QWindowsUiaMainProvider::notifyStateChange(class QAccessibleStateChangeEvent *)" (?notifyStateChange@QWindowsUiaMainProvider@@SAXPAVQAccessibleStateChangeEvent@@@Z)
qwindowsd.lib(qwindowsuiamainprovider.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall QWindowsUiaWrapper::raiseAutomationEvent(struct IRawElementProviderSimple *,int)" (?raiseAutomationEvent@QWindowsUiaWrapper@@QAEJPAUIRawElementProviderSimple@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl QWindowsUiaMainProvider::notifyFocusChange(class QAccessibleEvent *)" (?notifyFocusChange@QWindowsUiaMainProvider@@SAXPAVQAccessibleEvent@@@Z)
```

What library is required to fulfill those symbols?

Helpful questions related to this, which did not help:

- [QT 5.6 static unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714664/qt-5-6-static-unresolved-external-symbol)
- [Statically linked app with Qt gives error: Failed to load platform plugin "windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140293/statically-linked-app-with-qt-gives-error-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windo)
- [Qt static linking and deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment)

Answer (score 2):

I use a smaller list of libraries, you may refer to it:

```
Qt5Core.lib
Qt5Gui.lib
Qt5Widgets.lib
Qt5ThemeSupport.lib
Qt5WindowsUiAutomationSupport.lib
Qt5EventDispatcherSupport.lib
Qt5FontDatabaseSupport.lib
qtmain.lib
qwindows.lib
qtpcre2.lib
qtlibpng.lib
qtharfbuzz.lib
Ws2_32.lib
Imm32.lib
WinMM.lib
Version.lib
Netapi32.lib
Userenv.lib
Dwmapi.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and stupid: I was missing the `Qt5WindowsUIAutomationSupport` library.
I keep it as answer if anybody face the same issue.

In general, I had to include following libraries:

```
Qt5AccessibilitySupport
Qt5WindowsUiAutomationSupport
Qt5ThemeSupport
Qt5FontDatabaseSupport
qtpre2
qtharfbuzz
qtlibpng
qtfreetype
Qt5EventDispatcherSupport

Dwmapi
imm32
netapi32
wtsapi32
winmm
zlib
bcrypt
version
userenv
```

And additionally, it is required to startup the platform plugins before the QApplication creation:

```
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)
```